# Alert when Service Bus [Premium] failover occurs?

Tags: alert, azure-application-insights, failover, azure-log-analytics, azure-servicebus-topics

If I have a regionally paired Service Bus namespace with an alias, using the Premium SKU...
Is there a control plain event or other metric that will indicate a failover has occurred or is occurring?
I'd like to be able to configure an alert as part of operational monitoring of the system.

Thanks

Comment: There are a few metrics available like incoming error, server error etc but you need to determine which metric is likely to represent the failover. You can see the available metrics here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor#request-metrics. If you are looking for extensive metrics then operational monitoring tool like Serverless360 can be of help.

Comment: @NadeemAhamed - this is essentially my question: "...but you need to determine which metric is likely to represent the failover." You've basically agreed to my question. :-)

Comment: Yes, I don't think Azure has anything out of the box.  How about checking counter & values for "Failover Policy" if any.  Those failover counters can be indicator for monitoring.